# HTML JavaScript kendo ui Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, user-interface, kendo-ui

I have the min value and max value. If I want to create a drop down show from minimum to maximum number. Any expert can help me solve? Thanks

Comment: You want something like https://jsfiddle.net/8ba3a20x/ ?

Comment: @ketan ya, is there any coding alike that? by the way, thank a lot ya!

Comment: There is nothing just use input type `number` and set min and max value,

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried to achive task?

Comment: @ketan is there any solution if i want to select it? because if you want to choose a hotel room, it will ask how many person you want? something alike that

Comment: @GeneR i had tried a lot, but what i think the most possible is get min and max, if statement increase, put in drop down

Comment: So you are on right way, go ahead

Comment: @GeneR serious, but still missing something i think..

Comment: @ChengWan check https://jsfiddle.net/8ba3a20x/1/. I think this is what you want.

Comment: @ketan yeah,something alike that, now i just solved. thanks a lot ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use input time number for that. Which will allow you to set min and max value.

Check following:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5" placeholder="how many person you want?" style="width: 200px;" >
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ba3a20x/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

your question is very easy , so that I hope I can clear understand what do you want , as following code maybe is you want . Please let me know if it isn't you need.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="test1">        
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input id="min" value="1"/>
    <input id="max" value="10" />
    <select id="test2">

        </select>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var mySelect = $('#test2');

    for (i = $('#min').val() ; i <= $('#max').val() ; i++)
    {
        mySelect.append(
           $('<option></option>').val(i).html(i)
       );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank for sharing, but what i want is something alike min=2, max=5
min and max will get from database,
and the drop box will grab from Database auto change 2,3,4,5

Comment: @ChengWan hi you can add ajax to catch data from your back-end code